# Can I use python-social-auth in my `bottle app?

Tags: python, single-sign-on, bottle

I am going to add a SSO button to my web appication.

I want to use `python-social-auth` for it. But the supported web frameworks are Django, Flask, Pyramid, Tornado, CherryPy and webpy. It seems to not support Bottle framework.

How to use `python-social-auth` for my Bottle app?

Should I create my own `social-auth-app-bottle`?

- If it is not so simple work, which one is better:

  1. Move to Flask
  2. Don't use `python-social-auth` (and move to other Bottle plugins like `bottle-rauth`, `bottle-oauthlib`, etc)

Comment: It looks like python-social-auth has plugins for other frameworks . You need to implement what social-auth-app-flask (https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-app-flask) does for Flask in Bottle, but this might be more work than you had planned. It sounds like you might not be too far into your project to switch at this point. The nature of your question hints to me that you might want to consider a fully featured framework like Django, but I don't know enough about your project to advise further.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I used Bottle for years. I don't want to switch to another feature-rich framework like Flask. It takes more work to reimplement my project using another web framework than create a small bottle plugin for it. What about Bottle + Authlib?

Comment: In my experience, Flask is fairly minimal and simple to port to, not feature rich until you start adding middleware into it

Comment: I started with Bottle also, and quickly switched to flask when I found myself reinventing things that flask already had.

Comment: I agree with you. I personally used Flask, Tornado, and some more frameworks. But my project is grown up from private to teamwork. Other members of my project do not want to change web framework of backend. Thqt's why I'm still looking for Bottle plugin.

Comment: While searching for it, I found some bottle plugins on Github: `bottle-oauthlib`, `bottle-oauth2`, and `bottle-rauth`. What about these? Comparison between them or links to open source example projects will be welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

I use firebase from Google for everything.  It has simple javascript elements that feed an object payload to your backend.  I use `bottle` for EVERYTHING.  And honestly I found the firebase stuff the easiest and most robust way to manage your logins.

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, auth as firebase_auth
cred = credentials.Certificate("<yours>-adminsdk-AAAAA-1234567.json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

def checkToken(token):
    try:
        return firebase_auth.verify_id_token(token)
    except:
        return False

def login(payload):
    user = checkToken(payload['token']) or redirect('/logout')
    # <your code here>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try firebase in a few days.