# Why no Python Bottle plugin for Authlib?

Tags: python, oauth, bottle

I want to add social sign up feature to my personal webapp project.
I've searched for days, but found no Bottle plugin for [Authlib](http://authlib.org).
I found similar package bottle-oauthlib, but it says "oauthlib is deprecated, use authlib."

As I am an intimidate Python web programmer, it's hard for me to use Authlib in Bottle.

- Is there any example project built with Bottle + Authlib?
- Or should I switch Bottle framework to another? (As I've found some Flask + Authlib samples)

See also [my another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59495193/can-i-use-python-social-auth-in-my-bottle-app) posted a few days ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope no bottle plugin that I know of.
you have two good options:

1. use Flask (or another supported framework)
2. create the "plugin" yourself and donate it as open source ;)